# Express res.send mongoose result to ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I try res.send object to ajax.
If i try lije this works perfectly.

```
res.status(200).send(""+result)
```

But if i try like this not work.on ajax alert result is [object object]

```
res.status(200).send({result:result})
```

This is my ajax file:

```
$.get("/yorumal?w=<%-topic.konusayisi%>&sayfa="+daha,function(data, status){
alert(data)
});
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Try console.log(JSON.parse(data)); in place of that alert statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second snippet, you are sending back a JSON object, so jQuery is handling it as such.

If you change `alert(data)` to `alert(data.result`) you'd see the contents of whatever is in `result`.

If `result` is also an object, you would be able to access whatever properties that has too.

Comment: İf i try like this ...send({result:result+""}),works:)

Comment: What do you see in your console if you log `data` to it, as PEIN suggested? (i.e. by using `console.log(data)`)